# Python: Netcdf: Is there a method to get the overall average from one variable where another variable overlaps with a unique value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, netcdf

I have a netcdf file with a 3D int32 variable called tag (shape time lat lon) and a 3D float64 variable called p (shape time lat lon). The shape sizes are identical for both variables. The integer values for the tag variable have a starting value at 0, and an unknown number for its ending value (they are monotonically increasing). The 0 value is not needed, so I would like to begin an overall (space time) average the p var where tag value = 1 through the largest tag value n.

Example (array space (time, lat, lon)): The first integer tag value is 1. This value occurs at say (0,45,45) and (1,45,46). The p values at those tag = 1 array spaces are say 2 and 4. So the averaged result should be equal to 3. The next integer tag value is 2. This value occurs at say (2,100,99), (2,101,99), and (3,101,98), with p values at those array spaces equal to 3, 8, and 1. So the averaged result should be equal to 4. The last integer value is n. This value occurs at say (360,200,100), (361,200,100), (361,201,100), and (361(202,100), with p values at those array spaces equal to 1, 1, 5, and 9. So the averaged result should be equal to 4. When these are written to a text file, it should look like:

```
3
4
.
.
4
```

The python code below reads the netcdf files and variables:

```
import datetime as dt  # Python standard library datetime  module
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset  # http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/


def ncdump(nc_fid, verb=True):
    '''
    ncdump outputs dimensions, variables and their attribute information.
    The information is similar to that of NCAR's ncdump utility.
    ncdump requires a valid instance of Dataset.

    Parameters
    ----------
    nc_fid : netCDF4.Dataset
        A netCDF4 dateset object
    verb : Boolean
        whether or not nc_attrs, nc_dims, and nc_vars are printed

    Returns
    -------
    nc_attrs : list
        A Python list of the NetCDF file global attributes
    nc_dims : list
        A Python list of the NetCDF file dimensions
    nc_vars : list
        A Python list of the NetCDF file variables
    '''
    def print_ncattr(key):
        """
        Prints the NetCDF file attributes for a given key

        Parameters
        ----------
        key : unicode
            a valid netCDF4.Dataset.variables key
        """
        try:
            print "\t\ttype:", repr(nc_fid.variables[key].dtype)
            for ncattr in nc_fid.variables[key].ncattrs():
                print '\t\t%s:' % ncattr,\
                      repr(nc_fid.variables[key].getncattr(ncattr))
        except KeyError:
            print "\t\tWARNING: %s does not contain variable attributes" % key

    # NetCDF global attributes
    nc_attrs = nc_fid.ncattrs()
    if verb:
        print "NetCDF Global Attributes:"
        for nc_attr in nc_attrs:
            print '\t%s:' % nc_attr, repr(nc_fid.getncattr(nc_attr))
    nc_dims = [dim for dim in nc_fid.dimensions]  # list of nc dimensions
    # Dimension shape information.
    if verb:
        print "NetCDF dimension information:"
        for dim in nc_dims:
            print "\tName:", dim 
            print "\t\tsize:", len(nc_fid.dimensions[dim])
            print_ncattr(dim)
    # Variable information.
    nc_vars = [var for var in nc_fid.variables]  # list of nc variables
    if verb:
        print "NetCDF variable information:"
        for var in nc_vars:
            if var not in nc_dims:
                print '\tName:', var
                print "\t\tdimensions:", nc_fid.variables[var].dimensions
                print "\t\tsize:", nc_fid.variables[var].size
                print_ncattr(var)
    return nc_attrs, nc_dims, nc_vars

nc_f = './tag.nc'  # Your filename
nc_fid = Dataset(nc_f, 'r')  # Dataset is the class behavior to open the file
                             # and create an instance of the ncCDF4 class
nc_attrs, nc_dims, nc_vars = ncdump(nc_fid)
# Extract data from NetCDF file
lats = nc_fid.variables['lat'][:]  # extract/copy the data
lons = nc_fid.variables['lon'][:]
time = nc_fid.variables['time'][:]
tag = nc_fid.variables['tag'][:]  # shape is time, lat, lon as shown above

nc_p = '../p/p.nc'  # Your filename
nc_fid = Dataset(nc_p, 'r')  # Dataset is the class behavior to open the file
                             # and create an instance of the ncCDF4 class
nc_attrs, nc_dims, nc_vars = ncdump(nc_fid)

p = nc_fid.variables['p'][:]  # shape is time, lat, lon as shown above
```

This code returns:

```
NetCDF Global Attributes:
NetCDF dimension information:
        Name: time
                size: 365
                type: dtype('float64')
                axis: u'T'
                calendar: u'standard'
                standard_name: u'time'
                units: u'hours since 1800-01-01 00:00'
        Name: lat
                size: 287
                type: dtype('float64')
                long_name: u'latitude'
                units: u'degrees_north'
                standard_name: u'latitude'
                axis: u'Y'
        Name: lon
                size: 612
                type: dtype('float64')
                long_name: u'longitude'
                units: u'degrees_east'
                standard_name: u'longitude'
                axis: u'X'
NetCDF variable information:
        Name: tag
                dimensions: (u'time', u'lat', u'lon')
                size: 64110060
                type: dtype('int32')
```

I have been playing around with pandas groupby function, but I have not found something that works for my example yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works quickly. Checking the results, they are correct.

Using xarray to open the data, I then converted the data to a dataframe. After that I could use pandas groupby to do the computation.

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import netCDF4

# Open data with xarray
dt = xr.open_mfdataset(['../tag.nc', '../p/p.nc'], combine='by_coords')

# Convert to data frame
dtdf = dt.to_dataframe()

dm = {'p': ['mean']}
mean = dtdf.groupby('tag').agg(dm)
mean.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in mean.columns.values]
p_mean = mean.loc[1:, 'p_mean']
```